# error: cannot find symbol class ReactApplication

Tags: android-studio, react-native

I can't run my react-native project because of this Java Compiler error. Below is an image of error logs attached for reference:

[image]
[image]

```
error: cannot find symbol class ReactNativeHost  
error: cannot find symbol class ReactApplication
```

It seems like Android Studio doesn't recognize:

```
import com.facebook.react.ReactApplication;  
import com.facebook.react.ReactNativeHost;
```

Comment: Can anyone help with this one???

Comment: is it working correctly when u run this with react-native run-android ?

Comment: No, @Lucefer . The thing is the project syncs correctly, but when I run it on the emulator, it gives that error.

Comment: What version of RN are you using, and what does your MainApplication look like?

Comment: RN VERSION:   react-native@0.57.5

Comment: Can you show your gradle file which has the dependencies mentioned in it.

Answer (score 0):

Check your package.json. If it looks something like:

```
"react-native": "https://github.com/expo/react-native/archive/sdk-32.0.0.tar.gz"
```

(Currently this is the case after ejecting from Expo: `npm run eject`)

Then reinstall react-native:

```
npm uninstall react-native
npm install react-native
```

You package.json looks like below now:

```
"dependencies": {
  "react": "16.6.3",
  "react-native": "0.58.1"
},
```

Now try rebuilding your project in Android Studio, the error should go away.

Comment: I can't solve the same error with the above solution